# How to get protected messages in php

Tags: php, oop, function, protected

I have function like this in my class

```
public function browseNodeLookup($nodeId)
  {
    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("BrowseNodeLookup", $params)
    );
  }
```

I'm using it like this

```
$response = $amazonEcs->browseNodeLookup($node);
var_dump($response);
```

Now the object var_dump looks like this

```
object(SoapFault)#279 (10) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(178) "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
  }
```

I would like to echo that message. can someone tell me how?

I have tried like this

```
echo $response->message;
```

But i'm getting error since it is protected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use  `$response->getMessage()` instead of `$response->message` because message is a protected property :)